# Animation using Matplotlib - Cannot run loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am trying to create an animation using matplotlib. I have written the following code, in which I have created a function called `update_plot()`. This functions runs a loop, in which data change and `plot()` function is called. The `plot()` function clears old plot and redraws it. If I try to run a loop inside `update_plot()` function (even if it doesn't affect the plot), the canvas shows nothing. Does anyone know why this happens? Thank you in advance!

```
import math
import random
import sys
import time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas


class CanvasClickable(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.data = [[], []]
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.point_selected = None
        self.pressed = False

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        self.button = QPushButton('Plot')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handle_plot_button)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def plot(self):
        self.figure.clear()
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(*self.data, 'o-')
        self.canvas.draw()

    def handle_plot_button(self):
        def generate_rand_points():
            return [[random.random() for i in range(5)], [10 * random.random() for i in range(5)]]

        self.data = generate_rand_points()
        self.plot()
        self.animate_plot()

    def update_plot(self, point_ind, point_coords):
        self.data[0][point_ind], self.data[1][point_ind] = point_coords[0], point_coords[1]
        self.plot()

    def animate_plot(self):

        xc = lambda t: r * math.cos(t)
        yc = lambda t: r * math.sin(t)

        r = 0.1

        t = 0.
        while True:
            print("something")
        #     xi, yi = xc(t), yc(t)
        #     self.update_plot(1, [xi, yi])
        #     t += .01
        #     time.sleep(.01)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas = CanvasClickable(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Are you using jupyter notebook? Also, what happens if you put `self.pause(0.1)` after the `self.plot()`, inside the `update_plot()`?

Comment: No, I am using PyCharm. I tried it. It just shows a plot in PyCharm IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/interactive_guide.html):

As I understood, the loop I tried to run, interrupts the GUI event loop.

So I replaced the line:

```
self.canvas.draw()
```

inside the `self.plot()` function with the following lines:

```
self.canvas.draw_idle()
self.canvas.flush_events()
```